# Tag rename: shm to harmonic-oscillator

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should we rename [shm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shm) to [harmonic-oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonic-oscillator)? I don't think the distinction is worth having two separate tags.

To clarify: the purpose of this question is so that if anyone has objections, they will be made public. If there are no objections in a few days, we'll go ahead and make the synonym.

Or vote on the [synonym proposal](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/harmonic-oscillator/synonyms) Qmechanic made, if you are able to do so.

Comment: I [suggested](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/harmonic-oscillator/synonyms) that synonym five months ago, but it only has one upvote so far.

Comment: It's unfortunate that our tag synonym proposals get barely any attention. Hopefully this will put the matter to rest.

Comment: Fine by me. Do we express approval by upvoting this question, or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: Upvote the tag synonym Qmechanic linked to, and if enough people do that the whole matter goes away ;-) Failing that, I suppose the clearest way would be for someone to post an answer showing agreement, but yes, I'll take upvotes on the question as a sign of agreement. Basically my plan was to just let this sit here for a few days and if nobody objects, we'd go ahead and make the synonym.

Comment: "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym."

Comment: By the way, why is there a distinction at all. To me, "harmonic" means quadratic potential. What does "simple" even add?

Comment: @ChrisWhite no damping or driving. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Simple_harmonic_oscillator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags have been merged. This is a dummy answer to prevent the question from showing up in the unanswered list.